# java generics and inheritance question

Tags: java, generics

I have a list defined like this:

```
 List<MyBean> beanList = getList();
```

`getList()` returns type `List<MyBean>`.

Now, I want to pass the result  to a method that receives `List<Idisplayable>`
and `MyBean` does implements `Idisplayable`

This causes a compiler error.

Now it would be stupid to iterate over `beanList` just to cast it into `Idisplayable`. suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if the method that takes a `List<IDisplayable>` doesn't want to add anything to the list, then it *should* accept a `List<? extends IDisplayable>` instead, exactly to allow what you're trying to do.

The basic problem is that a `List<MyBean>` **is not** the same thing (or even assignment-compatible with) a `List<IDisplayable>`.

A `List<IDisplayable>` promises two things: It will only ever return `IDisplayable` objects and it will accept (via `add()`) all `IDisplayable` objects.

A `List<MyBean>` also only ever returns `IDisplayable`, but it will **not** accept any `IDisplayable` that is not also a `MyBean` (say, a `AnotherDisplayable`, for example).

So if a method only iterates over the content of a list (effectively being read-only) or only does a limited set of manipulation (removing objects is fine, as is adding `null`), then it should accept `List<? extends IDisplayable>` instead. That syntax means "I accept any `List` that will only ever return `IDisplayable` objects, but I don't care about the specific type".

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about being able to add `null`. Good point

Comment: @Lukas: it's a little fact that I took quite a while to learn.

Answer (score 6):

Make your method accept `<? extends Idisplayable>`

```
public void myMethod(List<? extends Idisplayable> list);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

If you have access to the method and it does not change the list, only in this case you may update the signature:

```
public void myMethod(List<? extends Idisplayable> list);
```

As an alternative option you may try:

```
List<Idisplayable> list = new ArrayList<Idisplayable>();
list.addAll(getList());
```

and then pass list to your method that takes `List<Idisplayable> list`

The point is that Collection.addAll is declared as:

`addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)`, as a result, you may pass here both `List<Idisplayable>` and `List<MyBean>`